# Why are BoxCollider and GameObject moving to the wrong place?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I have an empty GameObject which acts as a barrier. It has a Kinematic Rigidbody2D and a BoxCollider2D. When the game begins, it works perfectly with other GameObjects sitting atop it, BUT when the *active* boolean is flipped, the object transforms to the wrong place. Instead of going to the Vector3(0, -1060, 0), it goes to Vector3(0, -2932.16, -219.24). Why is it doing that???

```
public static bool active = false;
private Rigidbody2D block;
private Vector3 endPosition = new Vector3(0, -1060, 0);

void Start()
{
    block = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    if (active)
    {
        transform.position = endPosition;
        block.transform.position = endPosition;
        active = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a note, the Rigidbody2D is a component of the GameObject, so both 'transform.position' and 'block.transform.position' are the same transform.  So, you only need one of those.

Comment: Can you show us your Hierarchy?  Please identify the GameObject that has this script.

Answer (score 0):

It must only do this if the local positions are different. You are most likely working in local space, and not in world space.

Try either of the two of these methods.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html

Comment: How does that work? If I instantiate a new object, would I then get rid of the old one?

Comment: It doesn't instantiate a new object, it creates a new Vector3 that you can set the position to. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the Unity Editor right now, but I would try: 

`endposition = transform.InverseTransformpoint(endposition);`

Comment: Or just use `.localPosition`

Comment: The editor shows local positions for game objects (relative to parent) and you are setting the world space position (relative to world origin) meaning if there is a parent game object the positions will be different in most cases.